How to sticky multiple divs in bottom of window and see contents one by one while vertical scrolling in GSAP?
While vertical scrolling with scroll trigger plugin I want to animation given as below:

1st time scrolling: all 5 titles are visible

if scrolling again: 1st number title scroll up and paragraph is visible slowly (height wise) -- at this moment rest of 4 titles are stick to bottom of screen.

once 1st title and paragraph is visible completely the next 2nd title scroll up and 2nd paragraph visible and so on


Conditions are given as below:

div has 1 title and 1 paragraph

title is visible and paragraph is hidden


NOTE: the last 5th div (title) must stick to bottom it must not scroll till the 4th div (title) animation complete.
can you please provide the solution for this
Used only gsap scroll trigger plugin no other plugins
<section style="background:black; height: 100vh"></section>
<div class="provider-benefit">
    <div class="container-xl">
        <div class="row justify-content-xl-end">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="provider-benefit-list" id="pb_list">
                    <div class="list-item"> <span class="list-item-no">1</span> <span class="list-item-line"></span>
                        <div class="list-item-wrapper">
                            <div class="list-item-header">
                                <h3 class="list-item-title">Lorem Ipsum 1</h3> </div>
                            <div class="list-item-body">
                                <p class="list-item-content">1. Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-item"> <span class="list-item-no">2</span> <span class="list-item-line"></span>
                        <div class="list-item-wrapper">
                            <div class="list-item-header">
                                <h3 class="list-item-title">Lorem Ipsum 2</h3> </div>
                            <div class="list-item-body">
                                <p class="list-item-content">2. Lorem ipsum is placeholder text</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-item"> <span class="list-item-no">3</span> <span class="list-item-line"></span>
                        <div class="list-item-wrapper">
                            <div class="list-item-header">
                                <h3 class="list-item-title">Lorem Ipsum 3</h3> </div>
                            <div class="list-item-body">
                                <p class="list-item-content">3. Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-item"> <span class="list-item-no">4</span> <span class="list-item-line"></span>
                        <div class="list-item-wrapper">
                            <div class="list-item-header">
                                <h3 class="list-item-title">Lorem Ipsum 4</h3> </div>
                            <div class="list-item-body">
                                <p class="list-item-content">4. Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-item"> <span class="list-item-no">5</span> <span class="list-item-line"></span>
                        <div class="list-item-wrapper">
                            <div class="list-item-header">
                                <h3 class="list-item-title">Lorem Ipsum 5</h3> </div>
                            <div class="list-item-body">
                                <p class="list-item-content">5. Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- list items end -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<section style="background:black; height: 100vh" id=""></section>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    (function($) {
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
        const t2 = gsap.timeline({
            scrollTrigger: {
                trigger: '.provider-benefit-list',
                // start: 'top+=25% 50%',
                //end: 'bottom+=35% 55%',
                start: 'top+=20% 42%',
                end: 'bottom+=50% bottom-=28%',
                scrub: 1,
                ease: 'linear',
                // markers: true,
            }
        })
        t2.to('.list-item-body', {
            height: 'auto',
            opacity: 1,
            stagger: .3,
        })
        const t3 = gsap.timeline({
            scrollTrigger: {
                trigger: '.provider-benefit-list',
                // start: 'top+=25% 50%',
                // end: 'bottom+=35% 55%',
                start: 'top+=20% 35%',
                end: 'bottom+=52% bottom-=25%',
                scrub: 1,
                ease: 'linear',
            }
        })
        t3.to('.list-item-no', {
            backgroundColor: "#04B7A9",
            stagger: .5,
        })
        const t4 = gsap.timeline({
            scrollTrigger: {
                trigger: '.provider-benefit-list',
                start: 'top+=20% 35%',
                end: 'bottom+=52% bottom-=25%',
                scrub: 1,
                ease: 'linear',
            }
        })
        t4.to('.list-item-line', {
            backgroundColor: "#04B7A9",
            stagger: .5,
        })
    })(jQuery); // end of function
});
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.12.5/dist/gsap.min.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.12.5/dist/ScrollTrigger.min.js" defer="defer"></script>
<style>
.provider-benefit {
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 43%;
    background-position: -15.5% 51.7%;
    counter-reset: listnumber;
}

.provider-benefit-img {
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%;
}

.provider-benefit-list {
    padding-left: var(--size_30_half);
}

.provider-benefit .list-item {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: var(--size_10);
    padding-bottom: var(--size_20);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.provider-benefit .list-item-no {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #c4c4c4;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: var(--clr_primary);
    font-size: var(--font_24_22_20_18);
    font-weight: 700;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: all linear 0.5s;
}

.provider-benefit .list-item-line {
    position: absolute;
    left: 18px;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
    z-index: 0;
    transform: all linear 0.5s;
}

.provider-benefit .list-item-body {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.provider-benefit .list-item-title {
    font-size: var(--font_26_24_22_20_bs);
    font-weight: 600;
}

.provider-benefit .list-item-content {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: var(--font_20_18_16_14_bs);
    font-weight: 400;
    max-width: 550px;
}

.provider-benefit .list-item.active::before {
    background-color: var(--clr_primary_blue);
}

.provider-benefit .list-item.active::after {
    background-color: var(--clr_primary);
}

.provider-benefit .list-item.active .list-item-body {
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateY(0%);
    opacity: 1;
}
</style>

